# Fullcalendar adding a profile image to popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar, popover

I am using Adam Shaw's Fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/ with Bootstrap 3. The calendar displays events created by users of the site. I have a popover script that shows more information about each event.

I want to show a profile image for the user who created the event inside the popover box. The images are stored in directories for each user labeled by their ID and so throughout the site I have been using the piece of code below to display a users profile image but I just can't figure out how to do this inside fullcalendar. I think I need to echo  **$eventsArray['id'];** inside the code below but can't figure out how to do this. I know very little javascript.

```
`<img src="memberFiles/<?php echo "$id"; ?>/pic1.jpg" alt="Ad" width="100" class="img-thumbnail">`
```

Here is part of the json file:

```
    $events = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$id = $row["id"];
$fav = $row["fav_id"];
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['id'];
$eventsArray['title'] =  $row['firstname'];
$eventsArray['firstname'] =  $row['firstname'];
$eventsArray['lastname'] =  $row['lname'];
$eventsArray['id'] =  $row['id'];
$eventsArray['fav_id'] =  $row['fav_id'];
    $eventsArray['start'] = strtotime($row['start']);
    $eventsArray['end'] = strtotime($row['end']);
    $eventsArray['username'] = $row['username'];
    $eventsArray['backgroundColor'] = '#33CC33';
    $eventsArray['textColor'] = '#fff';
    $eventsArray['url'] = 'profile.php?id='.$row['id'];
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = true;
    $eventsArray['editable'] = true;
    $eventsArray['timeFormat'] = 'h(:mm)';


$events[] = $eventsArray;
}
$jsonData = json_encode($eventsArray);
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

And here is the part of the Fullcalendar page that receives and displays the events from the json file.

```
<style>
    #calendar {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
    <script>

    var img =  '<div><img src="memberFiles/<?php echo "$id"; ?>/pic1.jpg" alt="Ad" width="100" class="img-thumbnail"></div>'
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

     header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },

    eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.popover({
                        placement:'top',
                        html:true,
                                image:true,
                        trigger : 'hover',
                        animation : 'true',
                                title: event.firstname +" "+ event.lastname,
                        content: img
                                container:'body'
    });
                  },
            defaultView: 'month', // See weekly agenda instead of monthly

            firstDay: '1',//Monday
            selectable: false, // User can select - click on an event
            selectHelper: false,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) { // Get the start, end, allday when one event        slot is clicked
                if (confirm("Some confirm text.")) { // Confirm before action
                    $('#hiddenStart').val(start); // Set an hidden field with start value (String or Timestamp)
                    $('#hiddenEnd').val(end); // Set another hidden field with end value (String or Timestamp)
                    $('#hiddenAllDay').val(allDay); // Set another hidden field with allDay value (true or false)

                }
            },
            events: { // Render the events in the calendar
                url: 'json-events-feed.php', // Get the URL of the json feed
                type: 'POST', // Send post data
                error: function() {
                    alert('There was an error while fetching events.'); // Error alert

                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
      </head>

      <body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
       <!-- Popover using JavaScript to set content from hidden div --> 
       <!-- Popover 2 hidden title -->
              <div id="popovertitle" style="display: none">
    </div> 
               <!-- Popover 2 hidden content -->
        <div id="popovercontent" style="display: none">
    </div>  
        </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using

```
var img =  '<div><img src="memberFiles/<?php echo "$id"; ?>/pic1.jpg" 
             alt="Ad" width="100" class="img-thumbnail"></div>'
```

and then you use `img` inside `eventRender`. Even if you have an `$id` matching a user id, the same image would be shown for every event, no matter the user that created the event.

You should add the `user_id` to your json file (something like this: `$eventsArray['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];`.

Then, inside your `eventRender`, you would do something like:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var correctImg = '<div><img src="memberFiles/' + event.user_id + '/pic1.jpg" ' + 
             'alt="Ad" width="100" class="img-thumbnail"></div>';

    element.popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        image: true,
        trigger : 'hover',
        animation : 'true',
        title: event.firstname +" "+ event.lastname,
        content: correctImg,
        container:'body'
    });
},
```

Also, you seem to be missing a `,` after `content: img`.

Comment: Great, I can see how this will work. Only problem is the calendar fails to load. Is there an error in the syntax for var correctImg?

Comment: It works just fine. I think the alt="ad" in the syntax was causing some problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was probably the line break that I added just before the `alt` attribute. I added the line break so you could see the complete line at once (instead of having a horizontal scroll bar). You have to remove the line break in your JS.